# How to share iAd banner between views using AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, iad, appdelegate

I am looking to implement iAd in my app. So far I have managed to get them showing/dismissing correctly in each view using the below.

App Delegate:

```
import UIKit

import iAd
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    var adBannerView = ADBannerView()
```

View Controller 1:

```
import UIKit
import iAd

class HomeScreenViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, ADBannerViewDelegate {

let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate //Creates reference to the AppDelegate

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadAds()        
    }
    func loadAds(){
        self.appDelegate.adBannerView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.appDelegate.adBannerView.delegate = nil
        self.appDelegate.adBannerView = ADBannerView(frame: CGRect.zeroRect)
        self.appDelegate.adBannerView.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.size.width / 2, y: view.bounds.size.height - self.appDelegate.adBannerView.frame.size.height / 2)
        self.appDelegate.adBannerView.delegate = self
        self.appDelegate.adBannerView.hidden = true
        view.addSubview(self.appDelegate.adBannerView)
    }
    func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
        println("bannerViewDidLoadAd")
        self.appDelegate.adBannerView.hidden = false
    }
    func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!) {
        println("bannerViewActionDidFinish")
    }
    func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
        println("didFailToReceiveAdWithError")
        self.appDelegate.adBannerView.hidden = true
    }
```

My goal is to have the same ad displaying in multiple views that the user can switch between. However, it seem's that in practice when you segue from one view to another, ad's stop loading and have to start again. Is there an easier way to pass this adBannerView from one VC to another?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You might be interested in [this](https://github.com/perlfly/iAdExample) example. Here I make the iAD global not involving AppDelegate at all.

Answer (score 0):

in line

```
self.appDelegate.adBannerView = ADBannerView(frame: CGRect.zeroRect)
```

you are creating a new ADBannerView instance and throwing away the old one. So you are not sharing the view object, just the variable. 
Remove this line. After you've done this,

```
self.appDelegate.adBannerView.delegate = nil
```

does not make any sense, because you're setting it to `self` later. Remove it, too.

See also https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2286/_index.html