# How to add an AdMob GADBannerView to every view

Tags: swift, admob, uiapplicationdelegate, gadbannerview

I am implementing an AdMob banner in my app for a single `UIViewController`, and it is working. But I have so many views and I want to show a banner on every screen. How would I implement a banner that would appear on every screen? I am trying this in my `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    print("Google Mobile Ads SDK version: \(GADRequest.sdkVersion())")
    // bannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)
    // self.bannerView.adSize = kGADAdSizeBanner
    self.bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-MY_ID"
    bannerView.rootViewController = self.window
    self.bannerView.loadRequest(GADRequest())
    self.window?.addSubview(self.bannerView)
})
```

but its not working

Comment: it is impossible, you have to define the `BannerView` in every `UIViewController`

Comment: @Özgür Ersil , can you send me a link or explain me why? Thanks

Comment: Look at one of these links. [Stackoverflow iAdBanner between views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28904619/how-to-share-iad-banner-between-views-using-appdelegate) or this [iAdExample](https://github.com/perlfly/iAdExample)

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil not necessarily. You just have to position the banner for each View Controller. Check my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39575849/2108547

Answer (score 4):

Create a shared banner. You `init` it in your `AppDelegate` and then add it to the `UIViewController`'s that you'd like to have a banner on:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GADBannerViewDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
var adBannerView = GADBannerView()

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    adBannerView.adUnitID = "YourAdUnitID"
    adBannerView.delegate = self
    adBannerView.load(GADRequest())
    adBannerView.isHidden = true

    return true
}

func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView!) {
    adBannerView.isHidden = false
}
func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError!) {
    adBannerView.isHidden = true
}
```

In each `UIViewController` you'd like to have a banner:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addBannerToView()
}

func addBannerToView() {
    appDelegate.adBannerView.adSize = kGADAdSizeBanner
    appDelegate.adBannerView.rootViewController = self
    appDelegate.adBannerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0,
                      y: view.frame.height - appDelegate.adBannerView.frame.height,
                      width: view.frame.width,
                      height: appDelegate.adBannerView.frame.height)
    view.addSubview(appDelegate.adBannerView)
}
```

Comment: but here you just make 1 banner request for each window

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil There is only one request happening once the app launches. The banner will refresh at what ever interval they have set on AdMob.com. No need to send more requests.

Comment: @DanielStorm i am getting this warning in console. **You must set the rootViewController property of <GADBannerView: 0x14e6e52f0; frame = (0 0; 320 50); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x14e51b830>> before loading a request.**

Comment: @DanielStorm - I'm getting the same error as Museer. rootViewController needs to be set before an ad request gets made. What's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

SWIFT 3

```
func showAds(viewAds:GADBannerView,viewController:UIViewController){
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.adBannerView.adSize = kGADAdSizeBanner
    appDelegate.adBannerView.rootViewController = viewController
    appDelegate.adBannerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                            y: 0,
                                            width: viewAds.frame.width,
                                            height: viewAds.frame.height)
    viewAds.addSubview(appDelegate.adBannerView)
}


showAds(viewAds: adseHere, viewController: self)
```

Comment: Is it possible display different Ads on each recurring items?

Comment: what do you mean by different Ads?

Comment: I am getting same Ads in each recurring items. I would like to show each different Ads on each recurring items.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62485567/ios-swift-google-addmob-sdk-how-to-display-different-ads-in-recurring-items-in


Appreciated if you post your answer here. Thanks in advance